# Full space image in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, bootstrap-4

I want a banner like this:

#### When it is displayed in mobile

[image: Mobile]

#### When it is displayed in desktop

[image: Desktop]

For that I tried:

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 3vw;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="shadow card col-md-3 ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="90">
      <h5 class="card-title float-right">9999999999</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;">Get Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But in the code above, the text is aligned left, but I am using ***float-right***.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left: auto`

```css
.card-body {
  display: flex;;
}

.card-title {
  margin-left: auto;
}

h5 {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 3vw;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .card-title {
    font-size: 8.5vw;
    word-break: break-all;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="shadow card col-md-3 ml-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="90">
      <h5 class="card-title float-right">99999952341624624629999</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;">Get Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How to fit the text on the same line? https://i.imgur.com/2Wp65u5.png, without changing the font size of others

Comment: I updated snippet for overflow. Look at `h5` style.

Comment: If you find answers as correct, mark them as it is, so other people don't open already correctly asnwered questions

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with existing bootstrap-4 class changes

changes ml-4 to ml-sm-4 and add new class ml-auto to card-title div

```html
<div class="shadow card col-md-3 ml-sm-4 mt-3 mb-3 mr-4" style="background-color: #F0E78C">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZyROdEa.png" width="90">
      <h5 class="card-title ml-auto">9999999999</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body col-12 border p-0">
      <a href="" class="btn btn-block" style="background-color: #00BFFF; color: white;">Get Details</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```